# How to fix this VSCodium error (snap)?

Tags: visual-studio-code

VSCodium error (snap)

```
codium[2985]: segfault at 0 ip 000055e8cae07156 sp 00007ffd85391740 error 6 in codium[55e8ca93e000+75dd000] likely on CPU 1 (core 1, socket 0)

Code: 30 96 fe ff f6 03 01 74 0c 48 8b bd a0 fe ff ff e8 2f 16 23 03 f6 85 a8 fe ff ff 01 74 0c 48 8b bd b8 fe ff ff e8 1a 16 23 03 <c7> 04 25 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 64 48 8b 04 25 28 00 00 00 48 3b
​
snap.codium.codium-512f19e5-4ce0-4718-905c-ad16b2edf5ae.scope: Consumed 32.401s CPU time.
```

What is the problem and how to fix it?

VSCodium runs fine but KSystemLog shows this errors.​

Comment: Can you check if using the deb version instead of the snap package fixes the issue?

Comment: Does this occur when executing a long-running script inside VS Code?

Comment: I will try to use deb version. It occur when I start VSCodium without running any script.

Comment: I tried deb version, same error occur and after closing VSCodium I get application crash report. Same thing happens with Visual Studio Code.

Comment: I fixed the error, deleted an extension that caused it.

Comment: Error started to appear again after update to v1.82.0. Now it shows error multiple times.